# How to pass a dynamically generated list of property names and values in Neo4j for java?

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm using the Neo4j driver for java which lets you run a query with parameters. I have a dynamically generated list of strings which act as queries,
with each query having different parameters. Examples of query strings include:

> "CREATE (a:Person {id:{id}, name:{name}})"
>
> "CREATE (a:Person {id:{id}, name:{name}}, age:{age}})"
>
> "CREATE (a:Person {id:{id}, age:{age}})"

For each of these queries I would need to pass different parameters with the appropriate values in order for node insertion to work properly.

Code snippet for what I'm trying to do is given below:

```
try (Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
                String queryStr = "CREATE (a:Person {id:{id}, name:{name}})";
                tx.run(query, Values.parameters("id", "testId", "name", "testName"));
}
```

This piece of code works for non-dynamically generated key-value pairs of properties. For the purpose of this example, I've hardcored the value of
the query string (normally, the transaction would run in a loop and each query string would be read from a list). Now, when attempting to pass 
parameters, I can only do so using the syntax above.

For example, the syntax:

```
try (Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
                String queryStr = "CREATE (a:Person {id:{id}, name:{name}})";
                Map<String, String> parameterKeyValueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parameterKeyValueMap.put("id", "id");
                parameterKeyValueMap.put("name", "testName");
                tx.run(query, Values.parameters(parameterKeyValueMap));
                tx.success();
}
```

doesn't work, since the Parameters function requires an even number of arguments. Now, I'm not sure how to actually proceed. Obviously, the
Map object itself would also be dynamically generated (I've just used a simplified example).

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pass in the Map parameter directly into the run method (as the second parameter), instead of relying on Neo4j's Values interface. There is no need for casting of the Map object into the Values object.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know Neo4j but CREATE uses executeUpdate in JDBC rather than executeQuery as this is a dB write operation. Query is a dB read operation.